# WPF changing other controls property according to ComboBox selection with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm learning WPF and I have made a simple program to better understand a few things and I got stuck. In this program, I want to select the color in the ComboBox and change the foreground color of the TextBlock above it according to the selected. I've tried data binding but it didn't work (I believe it is because I use DataTemplate for the ComboBox), so I tried do it by an event handler but I don't quite get how the SelectedItem property works. Here's the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="My First GUI" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Sample Text" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Name="title" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30"/>
        <ComboBox Name="comboBox" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Name="rect" Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat={}  {0}}" FontSize="20"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And here the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           

            //Combobox data setup
            comboBox.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
        }    

        private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(comboBox.SelectedItem as Color);//This line doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to ask about all possible approaches to this problem and which is the best approach to complete it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`comboBox.ItemsSource` consists of `PropertyInfo` items, not colors. You have to retrive value of that property to use for brush:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var pi = comboBox.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo;
    if (pi != null)
    {
         var color = pi.GetValue(null) as Color;
         if (color != null)
         {
            title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color);
         }
    }
}
```

---

you can also use [Brushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushes) class:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Combobox data setup
    comboBox.ItemsSource = typeof(Brushes).GetProperties();
}  

private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var pi = comboBox.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo;
    if (pi != null)
    {
         title.Foreground = pi.GetValue(null) as Brush;
    }
}
```

---

To achieve the same result via binding use ItemsSource consisting of Names

```
comboBox.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

<TextBlock Name="title" Text="Sample Text" 
           Foreground="{Binding ElementName=comboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" 
           FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30"/>
<ComboBox Name="comboBox" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Name="rect" Fill="{Binding}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}  {0}}" FontSize="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But just another question, can I achieve the same thing using data binding?

Comment: @spencer123, it will require some changes. see my edit

Comment: I think the binding in the rectangle is wrong, it compiled error

Comment: @spencer123, binding in TextBlock was wrong: there was unnecessary comma (I was editing in browser, so it crawled in). otherwise it works

Comment: you can also add `SelectedIndex="0" ` to combobox to have some color (AliceBlue) selected from beginning

Comment: Ok it works perfectly fine now, thank you