# wpf listbox with colorized items

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, listbox

I am making an apllication which colorizes black and white Pictures.
I have a Listbox which I use to display my current Color Palette.

Hex code is hardly readable for Humans (at least me) which is why I want to colorize the Items in my ListBox.

My Listbox looks like this right now:
[image]

As an example of what I mean, I have a simple TextBox which is beeing colorized:
[image]

```
System.Drawing.Color? color = cl.ColorFromHexString(Basecolor.Text);
if (color != null)
{
    System.Drawing.Color col = (System.Drawing.Color)color;
    this.Basecolor.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(cl.ToMediaColor(col));
}
```

So my Goal is to have different colors for each entry:
[image]

The Listbox Items are assigned by using the following code (probably not best practice):

```
List<String> ColorStringPalette = new List<string>();
private void AddColorButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Color? color = cl.ColorFromHexString(ColorHexCode.Text);
    if (color != null)
    {
        if (!ColorStringPalette.Contains(ColorHexCode.Text))
        {
            ColorStringPalette.Add(ColorHexCode.Text);
        }
        ColorList.ItemsSource = ColorStringPalette;
    }
}
```

What would be the apropriate way to set foreground colors for the individual items of the Listbox?

Comment: As a note, `System.Drawing.Color` is not WPF, but WinForms. Use `System.Windows.Media.Color`. Assign a collection of Color objects to the ListBox's ItemsSource. In the ItemTemplate use the current item as Color of a SolidColorBrush that fills a UIElement.

Comment: The media color is handled in `new SolidColorBrush(cl.ToMediaColor(col));`

Comment: But does that make sense? Surely not. WPF already provides an equivalent of your `cl.ColorFromHexString` method that returns a System.Windows.Media.Color.

Comment: The Drawing color is used for painting on Bitmaps. Those require drawing colors. The issue is that one might add a 6 digit hex code (returns drawing color) or an 8 digit hex code (returns media color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change ItemTemplate and bind Foreground (it requires brush but will do converion from string):

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: you can also use color names: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815311/wpf-changing-other-controls-property-according-to-combobox-selection-with-datate

Comment: thank you, I figured it out with your answer and a little research. You might include the `<ListBox></ListBox>` around `<Listbox.ItemTemplate>` as it was not clear to me how it would be applied into the Listbox.